# Is this the right way of updating the mysql query with escaoe string

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to making a specific query as follow

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid IN (1,10,50,60,94,102)";
```

how can i use a mysql escape string for where clause or if i just use it like that, is it ok?

Comment: It should be ok just the way you have it.

Comment: UPPERCASE on reserved words for prettiness

Comment: @OptimuzCrime, sure,i just manually written it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing now is not an `UPDATE` query. You are only retrieving records from the database. In order to update records from the database, you need to use the `UPDATE` DML. The syntax for that is

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = newValue
WHERE columnN = value            // <== this is your condition
```

Returning back to your question, the way you are doing the query doesn't need `mysql_escape_string` because you are only passing integer values. Currently, more PHP developers are not using `mysql_escape_string` anymore because it's already been discourage and as the  PHP Manual site says this function is already depreciated. Alternatively, **[PDO_MYSQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)** or **[MYSQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** extensions should be used instead.

Comment: The main reason escaping isn't needed here isn't that it's all integers -- it's because the values are hard-coded in this particular case.  If the string's built by code, and especially if the values came from external sources, escaping (or conversion to int) is all but mandatory.  PDO and MySQLi will do escaping for you *if you use prepared statements*, but not if you're still just cobbling together SQL like a compiler.

Comment: yeah, sorry my bad, too many spelling mistake too, just saw it